# Long job title - print

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

For my profile when I've added long job title on print page it looks like in attachment. CSS problem?

[image]

Comment: That overlapped part looks like Zalgo

Comment: I'm not sure if I would call this a bug? You're job title is very, very long. To fix this, you could shorten it to "Deputy manager of Implementation and Development". That said we could work on a more graceful solution.

Comment: Simple CSS fix coming, stand by...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should look better now:

[image]